# How to determine bits needed based on mem sizes for format

Tags: assembly, x86, format, mips

I'm currently stuck on trying to figure out how to write out format for
•a one-byte opcode;

•a word-size of 32 bits;

•a byte-addressable memory of size 2^20×8;

•a register file of size 8
×
32.

I know that the opcode would take 8 bits and word is 32 bits. I'm a bit confused on the memory and register file size.

an address is 2^20×8=8388608, I thought it was going to take 23 bits because of it's value but that seems very wrong for some reason.

I'm also being told if i'm using something like **movi $val, rC**, the rC would be 3 bits. I don't really understand how when the register file of size is 8
×
32 = 256, so would anyone mind explaining to me by any chance? Please and thank you.

Also: how do i determine when bits are executed? Cause i'm being told that
**movi $val, rC** gives fetch+decode of 6 but the execute is 0.

Comment: The assignment says "byte addressable" so you do not need to multiply by 8. 2^20 bytes just needs 20 bits of address, as simple as that. Similarly for the register file, you don't care how big the register is, you just need to encode which of the 8 you want to use, so that's 3 bits. The _"x FOO"_ notation means _"FOO bits each"_. An 8x32 register file is 8 registers, each 32 bits.

Comment: Oh I understand now, Thank you!